# Android getting http request from clients

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api

I creating an application that can teather the wifi and act as like a firewall to manage the sessions to their clients .

***for example:***
 If i manage the clients http requests and response..after i authenticated the request ,then only the url has to be visible for them.otherwise it has to say page blocked.

In an Example provided by the google https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/sessions
It says it can manage sessions But I cant able to integrate it my project .Can anyone worked projects similar to this or anyone used analystics-api, help me to work on this

And how can i get the request page url from the user..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example in your activity ..From this code you able manage your http requests and responses..[session-handling-Exampe](http://www.lightrains.com/blog/simple-tip-session-handling-android#comment-1100)

Hope will help you..